# Find index and value of next match in string array

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have been looking for a long time now, to find any smarter solution than mine, to gather index and value of an item in my array. I can not search directly on the item because there will always be some other char in the string.
Here is an example of what I want to do.

```
// logcontent = ["f", "red", "frs", "xyr", "frefff", "xdd", "to"]
string lineData = "";
int lineIndex = 0;
foreach (var item in logContent.Select((value, index) => new { index, value }))
{
    string line = item.value;
    var index = item.index;

    if (line.Contains("x"))
    {
        lineData = line;
        lineIndex = index; 
        break;
    }
}
```

I want to only get the next item

```
lineData = "xyr";
lineIndex = 3;
```

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do. Do you want to have all Indexes of lines containing an 'x' ?

Comment: Updated, hope it is more understanable now

Comment: @TobiasMøller - instead of editing your question to include the answer better just mark that answer with the V :) it is clearer for future readers

Comment: Okay changed back to normal post. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use linq's [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = logContent.Select((value, index) => new { index, value })
                       .FirstOrDefault(item => item.value.Contains("x"));
```

If there is no such item you will get `null`.

If using C# 7.0 you can use [named tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples):

```
(int lineIndex, string lineData) = logcontent.Select((value, index) => (index, value))
                                             .FirstOrDefault(item => item.value.Contains("x"));
```

and then o something with `lineIndex` or `lineData` directly which is like you would with the original version

Comment: @MongZhu - I did not claim that the linq is faster that the loop. I claimed that it does not have to iterate the collection twice. deffered execution returns each time only the one next item matching the passed function, which is passed to the next method in the chain. Therefore in the case above if the item with the `x` in the value is first then the `Select` will create the object for it with the index and pass it for the `FirstOrDefault` which will return it.

Comment: @GiladGreen thank you for the explanation. Up to now I found also enough articles that describe this part, and I understood it. I already upvoted your answer, so thanx again for the lesson. Peace out

Answer (score 1):

If i understood the Question correct you want to have the next string containing an "x" in a string array.

```
 var result = logContent.Select((value, index) => new { index, value })
                        .First(x => x.value.Contains("x");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach with  [Array.FindIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy(v=vs.110).aspx) - which performs better than the `Linq` version

```
string[] logContent = { "f", "red", "frs", "xyr", "frefff", "xdd", "to" };  

int lineIndex  = Array.FindIndex(logContent, x => x.Contains("x"));
string lineData = lineIndex >= 0 ? logContent[lineIndex] : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

this code

```
string[] ogcontent = {"f", "red", "frs", "xyr", "frefff", "xdd", "to"};
    string lineData = "";
    int lineIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ogcontent.Length; i++)
    {
        string line = ogcontent[i];
        var index = i;

        if (line.Contains("x"))
        {
            lineData = line;
            lineIndex = index; 
            Console.WriteLine("index = {0}", i);
            Console.WriteLine("value = {0}", line);
            break;
        }
    }
```

result

```
index = 3
value = xyr
```

working [sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nwiG2S)